Is my derivation correct? (Holomorphic functions and their conjugates)
Let $f$ a holomorphic function and $H$ an analytic function on $\mathbb{R}^2$ (think of a Hamiltonian).
Let the function $f$ and the function $H$ be related by:
\begin{equation}
    f(x+iy) = \partial_y H(x,y) - i\partial_x H(x,y)
\end{equation}
The conjugate of $f$ is then
\begin{equation}
    \bar{f}(x+iy) = \partial_y H(x,y) + i\partial_x H(x,y)
\end{equation}
so that
\begin{equation}
    \partial_x H = \frac{\bar{f}-f}{2i} \qquad\qquad \partial_y H = \frac{\bar{f}+f}{2}
\end{equation}
and also
\begin{equation}
    \partial_{xx} H = \frac{1}{2i}\left({\partial_x\bar{f}-\partial_x f}\right)\qquad\qquad
    \partial_{yy} H = \frac{1}{2}\left(\partial_y\bar{f}+\partial_y f\right)
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
    \partial_{xy} H = \frac{1}{2i}\left(\partial_y\bar{f}-\partial_y f\right) = \frac{1}{2}\left(\partial_x\bar{f}+\partial_xf\right) = \partial_{yx} H
\end{equation}
Now, from this last equation I get a weird result (to me at least) and I would like a sanity check. I get the following:
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2i}\left(\partial_y\bar{f}-\partial_y f\right) = \frac{1}{2}\left(\partial_x\bar{f}+\partial_xf\right)\quad\Rightarrow\\
-i\partial_y\bar{f}+i\partial_y f = \partial_x\bar{f}+\partial_xf\quad\Rightarrow\\
-\partial_x\bar{f}-i\partial_y\bar{f} = \partial_xf-i\partial_y f 
\end{align}
now, since $\partial_x f = -i\partial_y f = f'$ (Cauchy-Riemann) the last equation becomes
\begin{equation}
-\frac{1}{2}(\partial_x\bar{f}+i\partial_y\bar{f}) = f' 
\end{equation}
I know that le left side is not identically zero because $\bar{f}$ is not necessarily holomorphic so the C-R equations do not hold for $\bar{f}$, but if it were, does it mean that constant functions ($f'=0$) are the only holomorphic functions which have a holomorphic conjugate? It seems weird to me.

Is conjugate of holomorphic function holomorphic? is related and may answer the question at the end.

@MarkS. So maybe it's not so weird after all...
